# Could not get access to rstudio-server with added username and password

Tags: rstudio-server

Hi I am using docker to run rstudio server

If I run on my host machine:

```
docker run --rm -ti -e PASSWORD=password -p 8787:8787 rocker/rstudio
```

The service succeeded in running, And I get access to the host machine by hostip:8787
login with credential rstudio:password
everything works fine.

But since there are more than one people need to use so I have to add user in.
I am running:

```
docker run --rm -ti -p 8787:8787 rocker/rstudio bash
```

then I am in container bash

I run:

```
useradd bill
passwd bill
```

to setup

but when I get access to the service using hostip:8787
The login page shows up but when I login with peter's password,it pop up a window with red words said:could not connect to r session on rstudio server

what happened? In this case could I add user? how?

here is the error message image, I can't copy paste it since there is some limitation in the server. May be it is helpful.

[image]